# Do companies recover CO2 and water from the purification step of cryogenic air separation, and how?

Tags: compressed-air, air, fluid-filtration, cryogenics, recycling

In the 3rd step of cryogenic air separation, filtered air is purified to remove water, CO2, and hydrocarbons from the N2-O2-Ar stream. Im interested in knowing what happens with that CO2 and water. Can both resources be recovered in a useful form? Can the CO2 be purified/ are Praxair or others currently doing this?

Context: Im doing research on a theoretical industrial process which uses pure CO2, water, and N2. I want to know if all these inputs can be obtained from a standard air separation facility (of course N2 can). Im particularly interested in CO2 recovery.

Please note I'm not interested in buying gases. I'm working on a publication about a theoretical system to produce protein from air and solar power.
In your answer it would be helpful to provide links to papers or websites which give descriptions of the recovery process (energy costs etc).

Thank you

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible, the answer is likely "yes". Whether or not a company does it is a value proposition. If you only accept links to papers so that you can continue your research would make this a resource hunting question which is off topic for the site. Please don't delete questions where you don't get the exact answer that you want.

Comment: If I can find descriptions of the desorbtion process etc, then I will assess the value of integrating CO2 recovery from air separation into our system. Currently we use direct air capture  (DAC) of CO2 which costs about 5-10 MJ/ kg CO2.